# Enable username and password authentication on mongodb sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, authentication, sharding

I have a mongodb cluster(1 mongos, mongo config replica set with 2 members, 1 shard with 3 members) and I have enabled internal authentication in config replica set. Also my backend code connects to mongos instance.

Currently, there is no authentication on login to mongos instance. Now, I want to enable username and password login on mongos.

After I run config replica set members using

```
security:
  keyFile: /path/to/keyfile
```

they work properly. But mongos does not work anymore. The command to run mongos is:
`sudo mongos --configdb configRepl/cfg1.example.com:27019,cfg2.example.com:27019 --bind_ip_all --port 20200 --syslog --syslogFacility local4 --timeStampFormat iso8601-local -vvvvv --keyFile /path/to/keyfile`

With command above mongos will not work and exits, bu witouht `--keyFile /path/to/keyfile` it will not fork and work.

I have created a user before enabling authentication. All mongodb instances are version 4.4 .

I would be very thankful if ou help me.

Comment: Did you follow [Update Sharded Cluster to Keyfile Authentication (No Downtime)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-sharded-cluster-no-downtime/)? The key point is option `transitionToAuth: true` If your application accepts downtime follow [Update Sharded Cluster to Keyfile Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-sharded-cluster/) which is a bit simpler

Comment: Not related to your question: Why did you deploy a sharded cluster with just one shard? It seems to be useless in my opinion, use a simple Replica Set instead. I would suggest to create a [config file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) instead of all these command line options. The configuration files applies also for mongos, not only mongod.